# Vectors and spanning $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: vectors

OK.......I've gotten this series of vectors into a matrix and rref'd the thing. I am kinda lost as to where to go from here.

[My work and question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e59Eo.png)

Comment: Why are you lost? You got three pivots. Do you know what this means?

Comment: I do not understand the circumstance as to if these vectors span or not. So I'm assuming that based off your response that the vectors do indeed span R3? In what case would they not span R3?

Comment: If you have 2 pivots it means the third vector is a linear combination of the other 2 so that the 3 vectors together only span a 2 dimensional space.

Comment: Yes, so in this case they span it (the first three, as you take the vectors corresponding to the pivots). You can double check this to convince yourself by calculating the determinant of the matrix with the first three vectors as columns. It is non-zero, so these vectors are linearly independent, hence span Euclidean 3-space.

Comment: You have done what is called an "echelon form" with no null pivot. That's enough! The set of vectors $v_k$ generates $\mathbb{R}$^3. It seems that you master the technique but that your question should have been : what does it mean that 4 vectors generate $\mathbb{R}$^3. Is that right ?

Comment: @B. Pasternak No use of "Euclidean" properties here.

Comment: @JeanMarie It's just a convenient name for $\mathbb{R}^3$ when you are answering on your phone ;) and I'm sure that the OP is not in any way confused, so I really don't see the point of your comment.

Comment: @B. Pasternak. Yes and no. For a teacher like me, the terms are important. There is a global agreement that $\mathbb{R}^3$ refers to the vector space only and "Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^3$" or "Euclidean 3D space" refers to the vector space endowed with a supplementary inner product structure, that is not needed here. That's all.

Comment: @JeanMarie I see your point. Nevertheless, these vectors span Euclidean 3-space, and it's not clear from the question whether the question refers to just the vector space or also the inner product space. But I agree of course that it's not needed here, as stated. But maybe the next question is to find an orthonormal basis from these four guys..

Comment: @B. Pasternak I appreciate the humor of your last sentence.

Comment: Thanks to Everyone. I understand the concept and how to interpret my work to form the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So that this gets answered; accept the answer if it is of any help.

If you are in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and you have any $m\ge1$ vectors and you want to check what the dimension is of the subspace that they span, you can row reduce the matrix which has the vectors as rows. The number of pivots is then the dimension of the space that they span. Here the dimension is three, but a 3 dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ equals $\mathbb{R}^3$.